# What happens to the gem when I salvage an item with a gem in it?

Tags: diablo-iii

I currently have no gold (just went shopping in the auction house... bought me some fancy and expensive weapon), but want to remove a gem from an item since I want to use it in another item.

I'm too scared to try it (it's a flawless gem and I don't want to lose it), so I'll ask: If you salvage the item, will the gem be lost, too, or will it get removed and placed in your inventory? Or will the item and the gem be destroyed, and maybe something will be added to the salvaged goods in return for the gem value?

Also, if this actually works, it would be basically a no-cost gem removal, if you want to salvage the item anyways.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Yes, the gem is removed and added to your inventory upon salvage.** Don't be afraid.

[image: salvaging talon]

Comment: This was also tested in the current update. As of 3/10/2014 you still get the materials for breaking down equipment into it's component parts. A gem being a component in this case, you get the gem back as well.
If I had thought of that before, I could have saved myself nearly half a million gold in the last 24 hours...

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with the current update as of 1/30/2016. I Salvaged a rare item that had a Flawless Ruby in it. Got the Ruby back as well as Veiled Crystal x 1.

Comment: Also, if you cube a legendary with a gem in it, you get the gem returned to you.